# How can I prevent re-render when window resize or lost focus in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component in Angular 6.0.8, which only contain an iframe.

page.component.html:

```
<iframe [src]="url">
```

page.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.url = this.route.snapshot.data['url];
}
```

Now, when I resize the window or click mouse outside of component (lost focus), angular will re-render it (lifecycle-hooks shows: DoCheck, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewChecked)

And browser will request the url in the iframe again, which is not what i supposed to.

How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most recomended ways (to solve not this concrete problem, but all unneeded rerenders) is to use change detection strategy on push (`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`).

[A comprehensive guide to angular onpush change detection strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

> By default Angular uses the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` change detection strategy.
>
> The default strategy doesn’t assume anything about the application, therefore every time something changes in our application, as a result of various user events, timers, XHR, promises, etc., a change detection will run on all components.
>
> This means anything from a click event to data received from an ajax call causes the change detection to be triggered.
>
> ...
>
> **OnPush Change Detection Strategy**
>
> We can set the ChangeDetectionStrategy of our component to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush .

**Example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip',
  template: `
   <h1>{{config.position}}</h1>
    {{runChangeDetection}}
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```